# usefulness of tdie with java exceptions inTalend

Tags: exception, talend

I want to know what is the usefulness of tdie comparing to Java exceptions in talend knowing that when an exception occur tdie exit the job and is passing the error to tlogcatcher .The same thing can be done by java exceptions (they also can be received by tlogcatcher and they exit the job ).
So why java exceptions are not enough for logging so we use tdie?/what is the limits of java exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use tDie after a component exception (like `Component-->oncomponenterror-->tDie` . As you stated, the java exception is caught : if you put a tDie, you'll only have 2 lines logged instead of just one.

I use tDie to put an end to a job if a condition is not met : for example , I can test the number of lines inserted in a DB, if it is 0 , I call tDie to end the job (with `tDBOutput--if-->tDie` , with a test on number of lines inserted inside the if condition).

This is more like a functional error than a technical one that I want to catch in this case.